# Javascript: loop through array of objects to find key value pair and render them in the table td

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the following table code created dynamically and I want to get the last 2 values stored in TD. the last td value is in the form of "key-value-pair".
I want to display something like below:

```
 <tbody>
    {{#items}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{description}}</td>
                <td id="newval">{{new_value}}</td>
                <td id="oldval">{{old_value}}</td>
           </tr>    
    {{/items}}
 </tbody>
```

here is the json obtained from the server:

```
{  
   "result":"OK",
   "items":[  
      {  
         "name":"abc",
         "description":"desc",
         "new_value":{  
            "description":"newvalue"
         },
         "old_value":{  
            "description":"oldvalue "
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":"abc3",
         "description":"desc2",
         "new_value":{  
            "interval":"newvalue2"
         },
         "old_value":{  
            "interval":"oldvalue2 "
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

here is the js:

```
  $.each(lists,function(i,items){
          for (var key in items) {
            if(key == 'new_value'){
              for(value in items[key]){
            $("td#newval").html(value + " : " +items[key][value]);
              }
            }
          }
      });
```

Similarly I'm doing it for the old value, just replacing the "td" id and value.
but what is happening is only the first td gets updated with all the values of "new_value" in the array and the remaining td's are rendered blank.
I want to display in such a way that it will loop through the array and find the key value pair associated with the "new_value" object and render both values for the respective td's.

```
<td>description: newvalue</td>
<td>interval: newvalue2</td>
```

how can i achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: ID of an element must be unique... use classes instead

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Sorry, corrected the table above. its rendered dynamically, so even if i apply class it gets appied to all the td's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Id of an element must be unique, you should use some other attribute of to group elements.

Here one possible approach is to use a class and a data attribute to specify the property to map to a field like

```js
var data = {
  "result": "OK",
  "items": [{
    "name": "abc",
    "description": "desc",
    "new_value": {
      "description": "newvalue"
    },
    "old_value": {
      "description": "oldvalue "
    }
  }, {
    "name": "abc3",
    "description": "desc2",
    "new_value": {
      "interval": "newvalue2"
    },
    "old_value": {
      "interval": "oldvalue2 "
    }
  }]
};
var trmap = {};
$('table tr').each(function() {
  trmap[$(this).children(':first-child').text().trim()] = this;
});

$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
  if (trmap[item.name]) {
    var $tr = $(trmap[item.name]);
    $tr.find('.val').text(function() {
      var key = $(this).data('key');
      var arr = [];
      $.each(item[key], function(key, value) {
        arr.push(key + ': ' + value)
      });
      return arr.join('');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>desc</td>
      <td class="val" data-key="new_value">key: newvalue</td>
      <td class="val" data-key="old_value">key: oldvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc3</td>
      <td>desc2</td>
      <td class="val" data-key="new_value">key: newvalue2</td>
      <td class="val" data-key="old_value">key: oldvalue2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet..well i took care of the remaining fields via the mustache.js..now i tried to add values into the td only for "new_value" and "old_value" object: but it table show up: http://jsfiddle.net/zPWDJ/14/